# How can I replace this while loop with a for loop?

Tags: python

How do I make this while loop a for loop?

```
correctpassword = "pa55word"
guesses = 0
guess = ""
while guess != correctpassword:
  guess = input("Try guess the password: ")
  guesses = guesses + 1
  print("Password guessed correctly")
if guesses == 1:
  print("That took 1 guess" )
else:
  print("That took you " + str(guesses) + " goes")
```

.........................................................................................

Answer (score 0):

You can run an infinite `for` loop using `iter` and break out of it when guess == correctanswer. Check the code below:

```
correctpassword = "pa55word"
guesses = 0
guess = ""
for i in iter(int, 1):
    guess = input("Try guess the password: ")
    guesses = guesses + 1
    if guess == correctpassword:
        print("Password guessed correctly")
        break
if guesses == 1:
  print("That took 1 guess" )
else:
  print("That took you " + str(guesses) + " goes")
```

Comment: Consider instead iterating over an `itertools.count` instance. This gives you the value for `guesses` directly.

Comment: It's not necessary that everyone follows what you want. You are not fluent with iter(int, 1) doesn't mean that the code is wrong. Comments in stackoverflow are not meant to just give more opinions. They are meant to be sure about somethings. I haven't done what you would like to doesn't mean that it is wrong. It just works. Right?

Comment: I understand exactly what `iter(int, 1)` does and I did not say your code is wrong.